# Java how to convert bytearray to class object?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I want to convert byte array to class object.
byte array is a data that read file.(file is not serialize!)

So, Is it possible that  convert Not Serialize byte array to Class???

because array byte size is so large, I have to use deserialize.

Comment: Depends.  How was it serialized to begin with?

Comment: How you convert class object to byte array if you dont serialise ?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: byte array is not serialized. A file made from C program is not serialized. so byte array is just byte array not serialized.

Comment: I get byte array from file. A file made from C program. Is it possible to convert bytearray(not serialized) to class??

Answer (score 1):

To serialize:

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(yourObject);
```

To deserialize:

```
YourObject yourObject = SerializationUtils.deserialize(data)
```

---

As mentioned, this requires Commons Lang library. It can be imported using Gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yeah you can use. try it.

Comment: thank you. I use SerializationUtils.deserialize without serialize. but it's not work. it occoured invalid stream header error like readObject();